# Creating custom OutputStream that handles two-byte characters correctly

Tags: java, utf-8

Basically, i want to redirect console output to javafx TextArea. I'm using this code now.

```
public static void init() {
    //GUI code. TextArea variable is named textArea
    Console console = new Console(textArea);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(console, true);
    System.setOut(ps);
    System.setErr(ps);
}

public static class Console extends OutputStream {

    private TextArea output;
    private PrintStream out;

    public Console(TextArea ta) {
        this.output = ta;
        out = System.out;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int i) throws IOException {
        Platform.runLater(() ->  {
            output.appendText(String.valueOf((char) i));
            out.print(String.valueOf((char) i));

        });


    }
```

However, there's a problem. ASCII characters work just fine (because they all use only one byte). But when I try to print symbol that takes two bytes to encode (Cyrillic characters for example), they obviously don't print properly and I get things like that

> java.io.IOException: ￐ﾡ￐ﾸ￑ﾁ￑ﾂ￐ﾵ￐ﾼ￐ﾵ ￐ﾽ￐ﾵ ￑ﾃ￐ﾴ￐ﾰ￐ﾵ￑ﾂ￑ﾁ￑ﾏ ￐ﾽ￐ﾰ￐ﾹ￑ﾂ￐ﾸ
>   ￑ﾃ￐ﾺ￐ﾰ￐ﾷ￐ﾰ￐ﾽ￐ﾽ￑ﾋ￐ﾹ ￐﾿￑ﾃ￑ﾂ￑ﾌ

Is there any way I can fix this? Maybe by using a different approach?

**Update**

This is what I came up with in the end. Thinking if I can optimize it somehow.

```
public static class Console extends OutputStream {

        private TextArea output;
        private PrintStream out;
        private ArrayList<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<>();

        public Console(TextArea ta) {
            this.output = ta;
            out = System.out;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int i) throws IOException {
            Platform.runLater(() ->  {
                bytes.add((byte)i);

                byte[] array = new byte[bytes.size()];
                int q = 0;
                for (Byte current : bytes) {
                    array[q] = current;
                    q++;
                }
                try {
                    output.setText(new String(array, "UTF-8"));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                out.write(i);
            });


        }

    }
```

**Update 2**

After a bit of optimization, this is the code I ended up with.

```
//Cut all the imports
public class LogScreen {

    private static TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    private static List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<>();
    //And some other unnecessary variables

    public static void show() {
        update();
        logStage.showAndWait();

    }

    public static void init() {
        //Cut window initialization
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new Console(), true);
        System.setOut(ps);
        System.setErr(ps);
    }

    public static void update() {
        byte[] array = new byte[bytes.size()];
        int q = 0;
        for (Byte current : bytes) {
            array[q] = current;
            q++;
        }
        try {
            textArea.setText(new String(array, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class Console extends OutputStream {
        private PrintStream out;

        public Console() {
            out = System.out;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int i) throws IOException {
            Platform.runLater(() ->  {
                bytes.add((byte)i);
                out.write(i);
                if (logStage.isShowing()) {
                    update();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] i) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                for (byte b : i) {
                    bytes.add(b);
                    out.write(b);
                }
                if (logStage.isShowing()) {
                    update();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Console is my own class. `public static class Console extends OutputStream`. It's in the OP. Cause is _System cannot find path specified_, but that doesn't matter. I pass to `write(int)` whatever `System.out` and `System.err` passes. 
This is fully working piece of code. If you don't feel like creating `TextArea`, you can just remove it from constructor, from fields and remove `output.appendText(String.valueOf((char) i));`. Then if you try to do something like `System.out.println("Привет, мир!")` you will get similar result as in the OP.

Comment: Sorry. Haven't seen that.

Comment: But isn't there a recursive loop? You redirect the `System.out` to your `Console` in which you write to `System.out`.

Comment: I thought it would be at first, but apparently `PrintStream out = System.out` creates full copy, not shallow one. So later, when I do `System.setOut(ps)`, old `out` value still points to default PrintStream

Comment: You don't need to write any code. Just use an `OutputStreamWriter.` That's what it's for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't work like this.

From the javadoc of `OutputStream.write(int)`

```
Writes the specified byte to this output stream. The general contract for write is that one
byte is written to the output stream. The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits
of the argument b. The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.
```

Which means for any character which consist of two bytes (e.g. `П` - 0xD0, 0x9F) this method is called twice. But if you use `PrintStream.print(String.valueOf((char) i))` you create a character based of those single byte, according to your default encoding. Which leads in your example to garbled output.

Instead of using `out.print(..)` you should use `out.write(int)` which writes on byte level instead of characters.

Following snippet prints the expected output to the console.

```
static class Console extends OutputStream {
    private PrintStream out;

    public Console() {
        out = System.out;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int i) throws IOException {
        out.write(i);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Console console = new Console();
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(console, true);
    System.setOut(ps);
    System.setErr(ps);
    ps.println("Привет, мир!");
}
```

Comment: And if you actually create your own class that extends OutputStream? I don't think there's any built-in to use with JavaFX's TextArea, like there is with files.

Comment: Ok, one problem less, thanks.
Gonna mess with TextArea now and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Hum... The first approach looks finer to me, but I suggest you override the `write(byte[] b)` and the `public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len)` methods. Just when you receive an array of bytes you can convert it to String through the constructor `String(bytes, encoding)`.

And what to do with the `write(int b)` method? Well... Normally it won't be used. But in case it is really needed, a little more complication is required then:

You must implement `write(int)` to receive a single byte an store it for later. And, the second time it is invoked, you have two bytes that you can store into a `byte[]` an convert properly to String. So: The method `write(int)` must work with two states.

Comment: But unicode does not always encode characters with 2 bytes. It can encode them with 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes. So, if I hardcode `write(int i)` to print pairs of bytes, it won't help, because sometimes it will have to deal with characters encoded with 1, 3 or 4 bytes.  I'll try overwriting `write(byte[] b)`.

Comment: Now, that's a good point. But, if you know a priori which will be the encoding, you can know how many bytes it will use. But, anyway, assume the worst case: Make it a _four-state_ machine.

Comment: So. First, when you extend `OutputStream`, you have to implement `write (int i)`, because it's abstract. Second, printing bytes in pairs is just way too hacky and it will never work. At least because even if all characters use 2 bytes, spaces and punctuation characters will always use 1 byte. And it will break everything.

Comment: Look: I don't think `write(int)` will worth a high complexity, because streaming APIs always prefer the `write(byte[])` methods. But in case someone will use it, it surely will write a _complete_ number of characters. So you just have to store them `ints` in a temporary byte array until some other `write(btye[])` is called or flush/close is called, and convert then the temporary array to String. That's not hacky. I'd try for it.

Comment: In the end I actually implemented both almost the same way. I add each byte I get to `List`. Then when user opens console I convert `List<Byte>` to `String` and update text in `TextArea`. I also keep updating it when console stays opened.

Comment: OK, but I recommend to you not to use List<Byte>. In shake for performance, use better an array of byte (fixed to, let's say 4096 cells) with an int to store the number of written cells.